# Page scrolling is not happening using JS Executor

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to scroll to the element "Top picks in laptops" using javascript executor but even though this element is present on the webpage, scrolling is not happening and driver is unable to locate this element on the webpage. What is wrong in this code?

````
```public class JSDemo {

    static WebDriver driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.noon.com/uae-en/");

        By topPicks = By.xpath("//h3[text()='Top picks in laptops']");

        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        String pageTitle = js.executeScript("return document.title").toString();

        System.out.println("The title of the page is " + pageTitle);
        
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
        WebElement ele = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(topPicks));

        js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true)", ele);

        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.close();
    }

}
````

**Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //h3[text()='Top picks in laptops'] (tried for 15 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:95)**

Comment: The website has 'infinite scroll' implemented. So the header is not visible (or in the DOM) on page load, you have to scroll multiple times for it to load and add to the DOM. Create a do-while loop to continue scrolling until the header element is not null. During each loop store the height of the page, break out of the loop if the height no longer increases after every scroll and header is still equal to null.